# Combinations of Unique Subsets of List

Tags: algorithm, scala

Given this list `List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5)`, how can I produce all combinations of subsets of the list, with the following constraints:

1. Each subset can only contain unique elements.
2. Each combination of subsets must contain all elements in the initial list (including duplicates). Flattening a combination should equal my initial list.

Here are some of the possible combinations:

```
List(List(1), List(1), List(2), List(2), List(3), List(3), 
List(4),List(5)) // 1*8
List(List(1,2), List(1,2), List(3,4), List(3,5)) // 2 *4
List(List(1,2,3), List(1,2,3), List(4,5)) // 3,3 and 2
List(List(1,2,3,4), List(1,2,3,5)) // 4 and 4
List(List(1,2,3,4,5), List(1,2,3)) // 5 and 3
```

I have tried something like this:

```
val myList = List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5)

val combs = (1 to 5).map(n => myList.combinations(n).toList.filter(x => x.distinct sameElements x)).toList.flatten

val step2 = (1 to combs.length).flatMap(n => combs.combinations(n)).toList
```

But the computation is too expensive:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: List(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5).toSet.subsets().toList.map(_.toList)

Comment: what about step 2? i need to figure out which subsets combined make up my intial list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val listLen = l.toSet.size
(1 to listLen).flatMap(x => l.combinations(x).map(x => x.distinct))
```

Please reply if it runs faster, otherwise need to go with other approaches

Comment: `val subsets = l.toSet.subsets().toList.map(_.toList).toList.filterNot(x => x == List())`
 `(1 to 2).flatMap(num => subsets.combinations(num).toList.filter(_.flatten.sorted == l.sorted)).toList` works, but only for small `num` of  combinations. As soon as I do `(1 to 10)`, I get the same memory issue.

Comment: what is your expected output?I guess, answer satisfies your criteria

Comment: see bullet point 2 in my question. I only want combinations of sets that contain all elements of initial array. currently i only factor in combinations of sets that have 2 different sets.

Comment: did you edit the question?I think the output was different before

Comment: how is this List(List(1), List(1), List(2), List(2), List(3), List(3), 
List(4),List(5)) unique?Please elaborate on what you need clearly

Comment: Each sub-list is a set (unique els). The entire list, when flattened, contains the same elements as the initial list (including duplicates). Is that clear?